# Using an MCU with built-in CAN controller vs. external CAN controller

Tags: arm, microchip, can, cortex-m

I'm planning to use the Atmel ATSAMC21J18A microcontroller in an automation project which has a built-in CAN controller. The CAN bus network may contain 32 devices, each generating data packets in 1 second intervals. There will be 16 such CAN bus networks connected to a single gateway node which has an NXP LPC1768 MCU (Cortex M3).

1. What are the factors and parameters that should be considered when deciding whether to use the built-in CAN controller or an external CAN controller?
2. Are there any pros/cons/constraints while using the built-in CAN controller?
3. Since the CAN gateway node will be handling traffic from all 16 networks, would it be a good idea to use an external CAN controller to avoid buffer overflows?

Note that I'm anyway planning to use an external isolated CAN transceiver.

Comment: External CAN controllers are deprecated, since you have already  MCUs with integrated one. Once upon the time there were no MCUs with CAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. An external CAN controller is similar to the internal CAN controller, but connected over a slower bus (higher latency, slower bit rate).
   There is no reason to use an external when you have a capable CAN controller on-chip (SAM C21):

   - Support for CAN-FD
   - Up to 64 dedicated receive buffers and up to 32 dedicated transmit buffers
   - Direct Message RAM access for the CPU
2. With some chips, using the CAN peripherals reserves a chunk of SRAM. But there isn't a real downside to using an on-chip variant.
   Only maybe when you need more than two controllers it would make sense, for software design point of view, to get many external controllers. But you'll have extra latency since the frames will not be memory mapped. Direct memory access is a big advantage of on-chip CAN with 32 bit controllers.
3. If your gateway has to connect to 16 independent CAN buses, yes. Otherwise, if it's only one bus, no.
   The LPC1768 should have plenty of memory. Looking at your story you'll be having an average of **512 messages per second**. Which is achievable at 100 kbit/s.

The only catch in this is that you can't have two identical IDs within a short period, else there will be an overrun in the messagebox. But the higher level protocol you're using should already have rules regarding the minimum time between two frames of the same ID.

The only thing to look for in on-chip controller is the **hardware FIFO**. If you only have a three-deep hardware FIFO, as on most STM32 controllers, you can overrun the buffer with a short burst of frames with too much interrupt latency. You'll have to add an additional software FIFO on top.

*If the gateway is to connect to a PC, please don't reinvent the wheel. Get something from Kvaser or IXXAT.*

Answer (score 4):

> What are the factors and parameters that should be considered when deciding whether to use the built-in CAN controller or an external CAN controller?

Mostly these are a thing of the past, since there are plenty of MCUs with built-in controllers nowadays. The only reason why you would use an external CAN controller is if your MCU does not support it on-chip. For example if you must use some sort of specialized MCU for other reasons.

> Are there any pros/cons/constraints while using built-in CAN controller?

It is superior to the external controller since you get faster register access, no overhead interface (no need for SPI, I2C etc) and no external components. Cheaper BOM, less things that can break, fewer EMI concerns etc etc.

> Since CAN gateway node will be handling traffic from all 16 networks, would it be a good idea to use an external CAN controller to avoid buffer overflows?

I really don't see how you can connect 16 different CAN bus networks to one node... that sounds like a complete nonsense system design. Are you sure that you don't mean 16 CAN *nodes* on a single network? Because there exists no sane way you can ever build that system with just one single mainstream MCU.

Assuming you mean 16 nodes, you should consider how capable the CAN controller is. There's generally two kinds: the simple ones that only have a rx buffer FIFO of a certain amount of CAN frames, and the "mailbox" ones that have both rx FIFO and dedicated tx/rx mailbox slots for higher prioritized messages. If you expect to receive a lot of different kinds of CAN frames, you should pick a CAN controller with "mailbox" functionality.

Your particular CAN controller seems to have the mailbox functionality so you should be good. "Up to 64 dedicated Receive Buffers and up to 32 dedicated Transmit Buffers"

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think having different CAN-bus networks connected to a single gateway node is a bad idea? What are the restrictions/challenges that make it infeasible?

Comment: @ravihansa3000 To begin with, how are you going to switch between them? And why do you have 16 different networks??? I can't even think of any application where have 16 different networks _and_ connecting them makes sense.

Comment: I am not commenting on pluses or minuses of the here described system design, only that any average automobile, like Mercedes for instance, has gateways which handle several networks (like 8) and direct them to single diagnostics CAN bus (OBDII).

It is used to increase safety, throughput, etc, but it is also eased by using dedicated gateway controllers.

Comment: @EmbeddedGuy They may use multiple buses for redundancy purposes. There's a difference between having a single MCU processing the input from 8 different buses, and some "relay" node that just shovels messages from one bus to the other without containing any actual decision logic.

Answer (score 1):

Since the MCU you're using doesn't have 16 CAN controllers on it, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Use one MCU per bus, and then somehow network them together.
2. Connect 16 external CAN controllers to a single MCU.
3. Use an FPGA to implement 16 CAN controllers in one chip.
4. Use a multiplexer to switch your CAN controller between the 16 CAN transceivers that are connected to the 16 CAN​ buses.